# What is causing this raycast click movement script using NavMeshAgent return a NullReferenceException?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, nullreferenceexception, navmesh

When I run this script copied from a tutorial, the Unity console consistently returns a NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. This occurs when I hit right click to tell the object to move. I have made sure that the object has a NavMeshAgent component, but the engine cannot find it.

To clarify, I am not asking what a NullReferenceException is. I am asking why this script returns one, despite that I have given it an object to reference and that object is not empty. In essence I am looking to identify why the reference is finding Null, when it should be finding a NavMeshAgent component.

[image: NavMeshAgent is a component on the Object that the script is attached to.]

```
`
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.AI;

public class CharacterMovement : MonoBehaviour
{

    NavMeshAgent agent;

    public float rotateSpeedMovement;
    float rotateVelocity;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        agent = gameObject.GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        //When pressing RMB
        if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1)){
            RaycastHit hit;
        
            //Checking if raycast has hit the navmesh system
            if(Physics.Raycast(Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition),out hit,
            Mathf.Infinity)){

                //have the player move to the point
                agent.SetDestination(hit.point);

                //ROTATION
                Quaternion rotationToLookAt = Quaternion.LookRotation(hit.point - 
                transform.position);
                float rotationY = Mathf.SmoothDampAngle(transform.eulerAngles.y,
                rotationToLookAt.eulerAngles.y,
                ref rotateVelocity,
                rotateSpeedMovement * (Time.deltaTime * 5));

                transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3 (0,rotationY,0);
        
                }
            }
        }
    }`
```

The object should move to the point clicked, but doesn't. I've tried using a serialised field and using

```
this.gameObject.GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
```

But I get the same error regardless.

Comment: Which line is indicated in the error?   Part of me would guess camera.main?

Comment: @BugFinder it indicates line agent = gameObject.getComponent... if I open the script by clicking the error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are only two variables in your script that could cause your NullReferenceException.

Your class defines one variable which could be `agent` or `Camera.main`.
Since other comments have ruled out `agent` being null you likely do not have the MainCamera tag set on your camera thus `Camera.main` results in your exception.

If that is not the case you should wrap the contents of your if statement with a try/catch to identify the object that does not have `agent` set.

```
       if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1))
        {
            try
            {
                RaycastHit hit;

                //Checking if raycast has hit the navmesh system
                if (Physics.Raycast(Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition), out hit,
                Mathf.Infinity))
                {

                    //have the player move to the point
                    agent.SetDestination(hit.point);

                    //ROTATION
                    Quaternion rotationToLookAt = Quaternion.LookRotation(hit.point -
                    transform.position);
                    float rotationY = Mathf.SmoothDampAngle(transform.eulerAngles.y,
                    rotationToLookAt.eulerAngles.y,
                    ref rotateVelocity,
                    rotateSpeedMovement * (Time.deltaTime * 5));

                    transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, rotationY, 0);
                    Debug.LogError("hello");

                }
            }
            catch (System.NullReferenceException exception)
            {
                Debug.LogError("This is the object causing the exception", this);
            }
        }
```

For further reading on debugging NullReferenceExceptions have a look at this [guide](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/136674/nullreferenceexception-in-unity).

Answer (score 0):

[You said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75075017/what-is-causing-this-raycast-click-movement-script-using-navmeshagent-return-a-n#comment132485325_75075017) the error:

> indicates line agent = gameObject.getComponent... if I open the script by clicking the error message.

but I don't think that's the line at all, because `gameObject.GetComponent<>()` shouldn't throw an exception, it just returns `null` if the component doesn't exist.

What I suspect is that you've got the script on some other GameObject, and that other GameObject does NOT have an attached NavMeshAgent.

Easy troubleshooting step here to verify:

```
void Start()
{
    agent = gameObject.GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
    if(agent == null)
    {
        Debug.LogErrorFormat("Failed to find a NavMeshAgent on {0}!", gameObject.name);
    }
}
```

Then see what the name of the thing missing your NavMeshAgent is. I'd bet it's not the thing you think it is!

Comment: Doesn't seem to be the case, but was good to verify. It doesn't output that line when I run. Have updated the post to clarify as I forgot to include it, but the error calls when clicking with RMB.

Comment: @TristanLittlewood if you're not getting a debug statement there then you have a valid NavMeshAgent and your NullReferenceException is somewhere else. You've told us *this* is the line, though, and that doesn't seem to be the case.